# Django get data from multiple tables

Tags: python, django

I want to fetch and display details(name_project, user_name) from both tables Project and User1

models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    name_project = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    leader = models.ForeignKey('User1', default='')
    category_project = models.CharField(max_length=50)
class User1(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    mail = models.EmailField(max_length=50)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

views.py

```
def list_project(request):
queryset = Project.objects.raw(
    'SELECT scrum_rest_project.id, scrum_rest_project.name_project, scrum_rest_user1.user_name FROM scrum_rest_user1,scrum_rest_project WHERE scrum_rest_user1.id = scrum_rest_project.leader_id')
queryset = serializers.serialize('json', queryset)
return HttpResponse(queryset, content_type="application/json")
```

but it displays only data from Project table in the json file, I want to display data from User1 table also

Comment: usind sql like that on django is a big "no", except if you have a REALLY good reason. Use django's ORM

Answer (score 3):

You should use [select related feature](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#select-related) :

```
Project.objects.select_related().all()
```

Answer (score 3):

Why are you using raw SQL? Learn [Querysets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/querysets/).
**1. Using Querysets:**

```
projects = Project.objects.select_related('leader').all()
for project in projects:
    print project.name, project.leader.user_name
```

> Note: `select_related` creates join with `User1` and saves you extra SQL queries when accessing `User1` model

**2. get only list of leader and project name.**

```
project_list = Project.objects.select_related('leader')\
                              .values_list('name', 'leader__user_name')
```